Joint measure which depends only on intersections
Let $(X, \Lambda)$ be a measurable space and $\mu$ be a measure on $(X^2, \Lambda \otimes \Lambda)$.
Assume that the diagonal $\Delta = \{(x, y) : x = y\}$ is measurable.  Suppose $\mu$ has the property that $$\mu(S \times T) = \mu((S \cap T)^2)$$ for any sets $S, T \in \Lambda$.  Is it the case that $\mu$ must be nonzero only on the diagonal, i.e. $\mu(\overline{\Delta}) = 0$?
This seems intuitively obvious but I can't figure out how to prove it.  My hope was to use a decreasing sequence of covers of the diagonal using squares $S \times S$, but I don't know how to obtain such a sequence without more assumptions on $X$.

I don't think I see why it is intuitively clear. If the measure on $X^2$ has the property that every measurable set can be written as a countable union of sets of the form $S\times T$ then the result follows, however if this is not the case, I doubt there is much you can say

@Carlyle Well, it seemed intuitive when I was picturing a unit square :)  Can you give an example of $(X, \Lambda)$ which doesn't have that property?

I realized it may have been unclear but I meant $X^2$ should be equipped with the product $\sigma$-algebra $\Lambda \otimes \Lambda$

Equipping $X^2$ with product algebra,
$$\Lambda \otimes \Lambda = \sigma(\{B\times T | B,T\in \Lambda\})$$
i.e. the $\sigma$-algebra obtained by closing the set
$$\{B\times T| B,T\in\Lambda\}$$
under countable unions, intersection and complements.
We then note that since $\Delta$ is measurable, so is it's complement, $\overline{\Delta}$. hence
$$ \overline{\Delta} \in \Lambda \otimes \Lambda $$
Which means we can write
$$\overline{\Delta} = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}B_n\times T_n $$
And since each $B_n\times T_n$ does not intersect the diagonal, we have $B_n\cap T_n=\emptyset$. Then
\begin{align*}
\mu(\overline{\Delta}) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(B_n\times T_n) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu((B_n\cap T_n)^2) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(\emptyset)
\\
&= 0
\end{align*}

Hello. Is it obvious that $\overline \Delta$ can be written as such a countable union of boxes? I believe this is true because of the proof of Proposition 2.1 here (linked here), but I can't see a simpler reason. In general a product-measurable set need not be of this form, right? (Take the diagonal itself in an uncountable space, for instance).

@IzaakvanDongen perhaps I am confused, but it seems that the definition of the product $\sigma$-algebra is precisely all those elements obtained by taking countable unions and complements of boxes.

@IzaakvanDongen but I realise now then that the diagonal being measurable and the question stating that the relevant $\sigma$-algebra is the product algebra, necessarily implies that $X$ is countable for the reason you pointed out

The definition I know of the product sigma-algebra is the sigma-algebra generated by boxes. What I'm saying is that in general, "$A$ lies in the sigma-algebra generated by $(B_i){i \in I}$" does not imply that $A$ is a countable union of $B_i$. This is because "the sigma-algebra generated by $(B_i){i \in I}$" also contains unions of complements, complements of unions, unions of complements of unions, complements of unions of complements, and so on (transfinitely)... I don't think the diagonal being measurable implies $X$ is countable - take $\Bbb R$ with the Borel algebra, for example.

@IzaakvanDongen you are correct. Apologies for my mistake.
